# How to restart QtSingleApplication?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I can restart my application with

```
QProcess::startDetached(QApplication::applicationFilePath());
exit(12);
```

But if I have `QtSingleApplication` new instance will not run. Is there way to trick `QtSingleApplication` to allow it to run new instance when `isRunning()` returns `true` maybe by some command line arguments or another aspects?

I'll be fully fine if I will add `Sleep(5000);` in the beginning but it doesn't look alike good design, I think I just need an additional mutex to detect if my application is gone :S what do you think?

Comment: communicate with the old instance and ask it nicely to gtfo?

Comment: Why do you want to do that? What is the concrete use case? Why is your application a `QtSingleApplication` if you want to run several instances of it?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I usually need it as single application but there is case when I need to restart it, it's hard to explain why but it's the need of application design, maybe bad design in this case.

Comment: @UmNyobe that maybe a way to go, I even will be fine if I will simply wait for it awhile it's closing.

Comment: I'll be fully fine if I will add `Sleep(5000);` in the beginning but it doesn't look alike good design, I think I just need an additional mutex to detect if my application is gone :S what do you think?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you want to start your app as new running instance, pass a specific argument to signal it should close any existing rather the usual opposite.

This can be handled as

```
//code to send to instances
if(myturn)
{
    if (a.isRunning()) {
        QString rep("Another instance is running, so I will ask to leave.");
         bool sentok = a.sendMessage(message_gtfo,1000);

        if(!sentok)
           return "some error";
    }
}

//code to receive message from instance
connect(&a, SIGNAL(messageReceived(const QString&)),
                        &this, SLOT(handlMessage(const QString &))
                        );
...

void instancecomhandler::handlMessage(const QString & msg)
{
  if(msg == message_gtfo)
     //proceed to exit
}
```

***edit:***

You still need to pass the argument to modify the behavior. Default behavior quit when another instance is running. New behavior waits till the other instance terminate.

Comment: thank you but it's already closing (old instance) I just need wait for it

Comment: @Heather you still need to have an argument to get two behaviors

Comment: sadly new application doesn't wait for old to be closed here, it just sends message.

Comment: because this code doesnt. Add some while clause after sending the message

Comment: fixed by adding `while (myApp.isRunning()) Sleep(100);` depending on aspect, now it works good

Comment: neat :). Note that the instance does IPC for you in the background at each call.

Answer (score 2):

One way to do such a thing is to use a little helper application (or script). The helper application is started detached and receives an identifier (ie PID) of the currently running program as a command line argument. It then waits until that identifier has disappeared from the process table, then restarts the application and exits.

This is a bit hacky/racy, but it works okay for me in practise. I use this in an update system, where I need to replace the running program with a new version of itself, which on Windows cannot be done while the program is running.

Answer (score 1):

If you are restarting your application from inside itself, it is by definition no more a single-process application (since for a short time at least, two processes running the same application exist).

I would recommend using some shell tricks to restart it.

On Linux with a X11 desktop, you might e.g. [popen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/popen.3.html) some [at](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_atq.htm) (or `batch`) command which would restart your application. You'll probably need to explicitly set the `DISPLAY` environment variable.

On Linux or other POSIX systems, a possible way would be to wrap the application in a shell script (for example `mywrapper`) like e.g.

```
 #! /bin/sh
 # script file mywrapper
 aftersource=$(tempfile -p app)
 myapp --aftersource $aftersource "$@"
 source $aftersource
 rm $aftersource
```

<sup>You'll need to improve the above script to handle failures and `trap` some signals... I guess you might adapt that script to Windows if so needed</sup>

Then your application would process the `--aftersource` argument to write some shell commands in it. If it want to restart itself it would e.g. write some command into that file to do that, etc.

Feel free to improve the script (trapping some signals and exit, looping, etc...)

Comment: I'm afraid that you'll need to rely on external OS support. Your requirement is contradictory (a single application cannot have several running instances)

Comment: at least it's not single application until I create new instance of single application